# Create mutually exclusive arrays on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$used_logins` with set of logins (can be large), and I need to generate an array of three unique logins like `$login+rand(1, 1000);` which wouldn't be in `$used_logins` array.

How can I do this fastly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do it in a database or such: Use the keys of `$used_logins` to store the data. And then check whether an element with the key exists.

```
$k_used_logins = array_flip($used_logins);  // Complexity is O(n)

$logins = array();
do {
    $l = $login+rand(1, 1000);
    if (!isset($k_used_logins[$l])) { // Complexity O(1)
        $logins[] = $l;
    }
} while (sizeof($logins) != 3);
```

Depending on the sie of the array this can be faster thant the naive way using array search each time. (One creates a copy of the array, but array_search slower than a key access)

Comment: `$used_logins` - it's associative array `'key' => 'login'`, so I receive an error `Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values` is there any method to make it unassociative array? And I hope you mean `!isset($k_used_logins[$l])`

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information on the array structure? and thanks for the notice of the isset error :-)

Answer (score 0):

If these logins are in a database, that might be the most efficient way - do a left join on 'available logins' to 'used logins' and you can filter on rows with NULLs in the right hand side to get 'unused logins'

Answer (score 0):

1. If the logins are always generated by you, you may use a unique number in it (e.g. a timestamp). Edit: you may also append the size of the $used_logins array ($login + count($used_logins)). Of course, this only works if there are no concurrent requests (you may add a random number to avoid that).
2. If other users may create the login, you may just check if the login already exists with the in_array() function.